# Tkinter,Canvas converting/saving details

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

here is my problem. I'm trying to convert my canvas drew into an image. First of all, I create the postscript of my canvas drew, then I convert it into png. The problem is that I obtain white images w/o changes.
So,there is my class:

```
class Paint(Frame):
 def __init__(self, parent):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.parent = parent
    self.color = "white"
    self.brush_size = 5
    self.setUI()

def draw(self, event):
    self.canv.create_rectangle(event.x - 7, event.y - 7, event.x + 7, event.y + 7,
                          fill=self.color, outline=self.color)

def setUI(self):
    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    self.canv = Canvas(self, bg="black")
    self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.canv.grid(padx=5, pady=5, sticky=E + W + S + N)
    self.canv.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.draw)
def clear(self):
    self.canv.delete(ALL)

def save(self):
    self.canv.update()
    self.canv.postscript(file="D:\\Новая папка\\test.xps", colormode="color")
    im2 = Image.open("D:\\Новая папка\\test.xps")
    im2.save("D:\\Новая папка\\test.png", 'png')
```

My main:

```
root = Tk()
frame=Canvas(root,height=200,width=300)

root.geometry("500x600")
app = Paint(frame)
frame.create_rectangle(10,10,50,50)
frame.pack()
b3= Button(
    text="Apply!",
    width=35,
    height=1,
    bg="white",
    fg="black",
    command=lambda :[which_button("Activated"),b3_clicked(),app.save()],
    font=25
)
b3.pack(side=TOP)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you creating a canvas inside a frame that is inside a canvas? And you shouldn't use `.pack` if the master is a canvas. It's bad practise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save the canvas drawings to postscript file, the background color of the canvas is ignored.  Since you have used *white* color as the paint color, so the output drawings are *white on white* which looks like nothing is drawn.

If you want to have a black background in the output postscript file, use `.create_rectangle(..., fill="black")` to fill the canvas with black color.

```py
class Paint(Frame):
    ...
    def setUI(self):
        # better call pack() outside Paint class
        #self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.canv = Canvas(self)
        # fill the canvas with black color
        # make sure the rectangle is big enough to cover the visible area
        self.canv.create_rectangle(0, 0, 1000, 1000, fill="black")
        ...
```

Also below is how you should create the `Paint` class:

```py
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x600")

app = Paint(root)
app.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
...
```